# Best pratice to save amount range values in db

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jakarta-ee, database-design

I have one account table in that table I need to save the amount range
I have one drop down that has the values  like `$25k-$30k`, `$30k-$35k` it needs to increase by 5 up to `$250k`.

I have planed to have all the values in one table (currency range) and I will map the id to the account. but my mate suggest that 
it is beteer to save the values directly to account table.

Which is a best practice?

This Question may be closed by someone. I need only which is a best practice only.

Answer (score 2):

First of all its wrong design approach to manage the range in varchar column.

I am not sure about your purpose to keep the range in varchar. If this is only for display and not required any manupulation then its better to change the account table directly.

But if you are doing further manupulation then here we have two approached to achieve it
1. It would good to have two saperate columns sale "MinValue" and "MaxValue" for limit range
2. If you are not suppose to change the account table then it will be good to keep a saperate table accountLimit and will have two column for range. Now you can associate the ID with account table. and can pick the value from the table accountLimit.

Comment: Yes, best practice is to not do it. Keep data and *rendering* of data separate